# Polygon Union not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, union

I am completely new to QGIS, so this issue might be really easy but I'm at a total loss on how to proceed.

I am attempting to combine datasets in QGIS utilizing the Polygon Union command, but am running into issues with this.

My first data set is comprised of various land covers and appears as below following clipping:

[image: Land Cover]

My second data set is comprised of various soil types and appears as below following clipping:

[image: Soil Types]

When I run the SAGA Polygon Union command, it does not seem to have subdivided the land covers with the soil types. Instead, it seems like only the land covers was considered. Below is a picture of the command inputs along with the output:

[image: Final Output]

I've been perplexed by this issue for a few days and the only guidance I've found relates to the Coordinate Reference Systems, however, whenever I change the systems so that they are all identical, it results in the soils dataset completely disappearing.

If it's relevant, the CRS for the land covers is EPSG: 2260 and for the soils (when they fall where they're supposed to) is EPSG: 4326.

Also if it's relevant, my QGIS version is 3.2.3-Bonn.

Comment: You need to use the same crs for both layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both layers need to use the same crs.  Use the tool vector general > reproject layer and reproject one of your layers to match the crs of the other layer:

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Gonna hold off on accepting for a day just in case something else comes in, otherwise, I'll give you the check.